# I have only been able to borrow

Tags: vocabulary

> “I ***have only been*** able to borrow about RM100,000 from friends and
>   relatives so far. I can’t get any more,” Chin said when contacted.

What does "have only been" mean in the sentence above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that RM100,000 was the total amount he was able to borrow at some point in the past - he couldn't borrow any more.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the right sense of this sentence, we'll have to look at the following sentences:

1- I was able to borrow about RM100,000. (simple past)

2- I have been able to borrow about RM100,000 so far. (present perfect)

In the first case, the chances to borrow more money are over.
In the second case, the chances are not over. I have been able to borrow RM100,000 from friends and relatives so far, but there is still a possibility that I'll be able to borrow more money.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the word order and placing the word 'only' elsewhere in the sentence can subtly change the meaning, and convey more or less information about the ways in which Chin has tried to acquire money.

Chin could have said "I have been able to borrow **only** about RM100,000 ...". By placing 'only' immediately before the amount, 'only' refers to the amount; Chin has borrowed RM100,000 but no more. This sentence is about the limits of Chin's success at borrowing money, but gives no information about other ways of acquiring money.

By placing 'only' after 'I have', 'only' refers to the verb: the sentence means that Chin **has been able** to borrow money but **has not been able** to acquire money by other means; Chin has not been able to earn, beg, steal, or find money down the back of the sofa.